# Flexbox child : any way to reset "display: none"?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Typically I set lengthy menus on my mobile site to an initial `display: none` and use a `Javascript` "Expand" button to switch them back to `display: flex` (or whatever).

But this time around, I can't hide the flex parent. I have to hide only certain flex children, because certain others must be visible. But without a `display: flex-child` to switch back to...

Is there a solution?

Comment: Could you post some code, like how you're hiding, and how are you trying to show it again?

Answer (score 4):

Flex items are flex items not because they have some special `display` value, but because they are children of a flex container. The `display` value is almost irrelevant since it will be blockified anyways.

So you can just toggle between `display: none` and `display: block`, for example.

But also consider [collapsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#visibility-collapse):

> Specifying `visibility: collapse` on a flex item causes it to become a
>   *collapsed flex item*, producing an effect similar to `visibility: collapse` on a table-row or table-column: the collapsed flex item is
>   removed from rendering entirely, but leaves behind a "strut" that
>   keeps the flex line’s cross-size stable.
>
> Thus, if a flex container has only one flex line, dynamically
>   collapsing or uncollapsing items may change the flex container’s main
>   size, but is guaranteed to have no effect on its cross size and won’t
>   cause the rest of the page’s layout to "wobble".

```css
ul, ul > li {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
ul > li {
  border: 1px solid;
}
ul > li:not(:target):not(:hover) > ul {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="nav-about"><a href="#nav-about">About</a>
  <li id="nav-projects"><a href="#nav-projects">Projects</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Art</li>
      <li>Architecture</li>
      <li>Music</li>
    </ul>
  <li id="nav-interact"><a href="#nav-interact">Interact</a>
</ul>
<p>Hover over the menu above: each section expands to show its sub-items. In order to keep the menu width stable, <code>visibility: collapse</code> is used instead of <code>display: none</code>. This results in a sidebar that is always wide enough for the word “Architecture”, even though it is not always visible.</p>
```

Comment: The display type is relevant when you need to distinguish between a block container box, a table box, or some other type of box, or even a nested flex container. But if all your flex items are simple block containers then display: block is sufficient.